# Why doesn't Xcode's error checking work for my test folder?

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors

Any classes I put within my CallInTests folder no longer get checked for errors. Is there a way to change my settings or the file structure so I can have these files checked for errors?

[image: Error-less Screenshot]

My colleagues also have this issue so it isn't a local problem.
These are scripts I use within the terminal so don't actually compile with the project but I've thrown them in so it's easy to update them on git.

I've tried deleting derived data, cleaning and rebuilding and restarting Xcode to no avail. For now I'm building the class in a playground then copy and pasting it in but I'd like a better solution.

Comment: Are you building the test target while you are building the app?

Comment: @LucaD I'm not sure, how can I check this?

Comment: You have to go to your scheme settings -> Build tab -> There should be the test target into the list

Comment: @tastycat Please don't add thanks to questions via edits. We are supposed to *remove* those, not to add them.

Comment: @LucaD that did the trick, thanks. Feel free to put it as an answer.
Should I be added it to tests rather than build as the app won't actually use this folder?

Comment: I answered. I'm glad it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building the test target while you are building the app?

You have to go to your scheme settings -> Build tab -> There should be the test target into the list